# Radio Button selected value not displayed in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button, haml

I have radio button in a rails form.
When I go back to edit the form, the selected value is correctly displayed.
But when I do the same in production, there is no selected radio button displayed.
I therefore created this if statement below, to make it extra clear that a radio button should be displayed as selected. Still the same problem: It works in development but not in production environment.

Here is my haml edit form:

```
- f2.object.checkout_element.options.each do |option|
                .form-radio-vertical
                  - if option == f2.object.result
                    = f2.radio_button :result, option, checked: "checked"
                  - else
                    = f2.radio_button :result, option
                  = f2.label :result, option
```

Comment: Could start a rails server in production env in your local and test it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:
the option had a space at the first position of the string while the result had not (string was stripped by a gem). I stripped the option as well and it worked.